# R studio - using grepl() to grab specific characters and populate a new column in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data set in R studio (Aud) that looks like the following. ID is of type Character and Function is of type character as well

```
ID                         Function
F04                        FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011
F05                        FZ000AGH WZ004ABD
F06                        FZ0005ABD
```

my goal is to attempt and extract only the "FZ", "TTY", "WB", "FR", "WZ", "ABD" from all the rows in the data set and place them in a new unique column in the data set so that i have something like the following as an example

```
ID     Function                  SUBFUN1  SUBFUN2  SUBFUN3  SUBFUN4 SUBFUN5
F04    FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011  FZ       TTY      WB       FR      DR
```

I want to individualize the functions since they represent a certain behavior and that way i can plot per ID the behavior or functions which occur the most over a course of time

I tried the the following

```
Aud$Subfun1<-
ifelse(grepl("FZ",Aud$Functions.NO.)==T,"FZ", "Other"))

Aud$Subfun2<-
ifelse(grepl("TTY",Aud$Functions.NO.)==T,"TTY","Other"))
```

I get the error message below in my attempts for subfun1 & subfun2:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Subfun1, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 343456

 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Subfun2, value = logical(0)) : 
      replacement has 0 rows, data has 343456
```

I also tried substring() but substring seems to require a start and an end for the character range that needs to be captured in the new column. This is not ideal as the codes FZ, TTY, WB, FR, WZ and ABD all appear at different parts of the function string

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to separate out *any* set of capital letters from that column, or just those *specific* sets of capital letters?

Comment: @camille - yes, looking to take out those specific sets of capital letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
Aud <- data.frame(
  ID = c("F04", "F05", "F06"), 
  Function = c("FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011", "FZ000AGH WZ004ABD", "FZ0005ABD"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
setDT(Aud)

cbind(Aud, Aud[, tstrsplit(Function, "[0-9]+| ")])
    ID                 Function V1  V2   V3   V4   V5
1: F04 FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011 FZ TTY   WB   FR   DR
2: F05        FZ000AGH WZ004ABD FZ AGH   WZ  ABD <NA>
3: F06                FZ0005ABD FZ ABD <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Staying in base R one could do something like the following:

```
our_split <- strsplit(Aud$Function, "[0-9]+| ")

cbind(
  Aud,
  do.call(rbind, lapply(our_split, "length<-", max(lengths(our_split))))
)
```

Comment: never knew tstrsplit!! that one will go into my toolbox more often from now on :)

Comment: Thanks to you Snoram - your answer helped me break down the values a little better. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One can use `tidyr::separate` to divide `Function` column in multiple columns using `regex` as separator.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate(Function, into = paste("V",1:5, sep=""),  
           sep = "([^[:alpha:]]+)", fill="right", extra = "drop")

#    ID V1  V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1 F04 FZ TTY   WB   FR   DR
# 2 F05 FZ AGH   WZ  ABD <NA>
# 3 F06 FZ ABD <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

`([^[:alpha:]]+)` : Separate on anything other than alphabates

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID                         Function
F04                        'FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011'
F05                        'FZ000AGH WZ004ABD'
F06                        FZ0005ABD",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Interesting, i tried your approach; however i get an error message. Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not an integer vector. the function data column is defined as a factor and same with ID is a factor. I wonder why this error appears

Comment: @vbala2014 Please try with the sample provided by me first. Otherwise please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` way that makes use of `stringr::str_extract_all` to get a nested list of all occurrences of the search terms, then spreads into the wide format you have as your desired output. If you were extracting *any* sets of consecutive capital letters, you could use `"[A-Z]+"` as your search term, but since you said it was these *specific* IDs, you need a more specific search term. If putting the regex becomes cumbersome, say if you have a vector of many of these IDs, you could paste it together and collapse by `|`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Aud <- data_frame(
  ID = c("F04", "F05", "F06"), 
  Function = c("FZ000TTY WB002FR088DR011", "FZ000AGH WZ004ABD", "FZ0005ABD")
)

search_terms <- "(FZ|TTY|WB|FR|WZ|ABD)"

Aud %>%
  mutate(code = str_extract_all(Function, search_terms)) %>%
  select(-Function) %>%
  unnest(code) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(subfun = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key = subfun, value = code, sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID    subfun1 subfun2 subfun3 subfun4
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 F04   FZ      TTY     WB      FR     
#> 2 F05   FZ      WZ      ABD     <NA>   
#> 3 F06   FZ      ABD     <NA>    <NA>
```

Created on 2018-07-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).